# How to verify email in Parse with Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am looking on how to verify email in Parse with Swift (send an email to the person and use a link in the email to confirm that the email belongs to them). I have only found how to do it in Objective-C. How would I go about doing this in Swift? I saw that in Parse there is a column called emailVerified and it's a boolean and that's what I'm assuming it means. Is that what it means or am I mistaken?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by verify? Do you mean conforms to email address syntax or do you mean actually resolve to a real address?

Comment: @ScottMcGready Oh sorry about that. Let me go add a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Parse.com, navigate to your app's Dashboard and click on the Settings tab. You can enable email verification in the Email settings panel.

There is also a small section in the developers guide linked here [Parse verifying emails](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-verifying-emails)

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! I just did it!